Rust reqwest get 411 error but same format work with other language (python, httpie)
I'm about to create http client for query some data from server which I had done on python or either test with Httpie it work and server respond as expected but when I use Rust reqwest is always get 411 error (I have try other crates like ureq, hyper, awc also have same issue).
this could be a very simple request script but I dont know why only Rust that return 411 error
this python code
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/GetPut"
querystring = {"TYPE":"GET"}
payload = ":HEADER\nTABLE=VERSION\nVERSION\nSTRING\n1.00\nTABLE=CURRENT_ATTRIBUTES\nSERIAL_NUM\nSTRING\nAB22D002000CD3C28\n"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "request",
    "Host": "127.0.0.1",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
print(response.text)

and here Rust with reqwest
let serial_num = "AB22D002000CD3C28";
let body = format!(":HEADER\nTABLE=VERSION\nVERSION\nSTRING\n1.00\nTABLE=CURRENT_ATTRIBUTES\nSERIAL_NUM\nSTRING\n{}\n",serial_num);

let body_length = body.chars().count().to_string();
let length = body_length.as_str();

let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
headers.insert(CONTENT_LENGTH, HeaderValue::from_str(length).unwrap());
headers.insert(CONTENT_TYPE, HeaderValue::from_static("text/plain; charset=utf-8"));
headers.insert(HOST, HeaderValue::from_static("127.0.0.1"));
headers.insert(USER_AGENT, HeaderValue::from_static("reqwest"));

let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/GetPut";
let query = [("TYPE", "GET")];

let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let (cli, req) = client
        .post(url)
        .headers(headers)
        .query(&query)
        .body(body)
        .build_split();

let req = req.unwrap();
println!("{:?}",cli);
println!("{:?}",req);

let response = cli.execute(req).await.unwrap();

println!("{:?}", response.headers());
println!("{:?}", response.status());
println!("{}", response.text().await.unwrap());

I have try to check with Python , Httpie with same format and server response as normal only Rust that always get 411 error, I also try ureq, hyper, awc it also same error

yeah that very confusing me I also inspect the request from Rust , Python and Httpie I didnt notice an issue except that body text send out in different way but I dont know how to check that

I tested your Rust code against a random echo server, and it works fine. So my assumption is that whatever http://127.0.0.1:3000/GetPut is, it's doing something wrong

Note that the Content-Length header is supposed to be in bytes, so the proper way of getting it would be body.len(), not body.chars().count() (not the issue here since you only have ASCII characters so they should be the same).

I needed to build the client with http1_title_case_headers() as reqwest::headers are lower case by default:
// Before
let client = reqwest::Client::new();

// After
let client = reqwest::ClientBuilder::new()
    .http1_title_case_headers()
    .build()
    .unwrap();


Well, then that server isn't compliant with the HTTP specification, as headers are case-insensitive.

You should accept your own answer as the solution
